# Wave disappearing on oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope

I am trying to observe a wave on my oscilloscope (with a CRT display). I can see a point on the screen tracing out the waveform, but the wave does not stay on the screen for me to say. This wave is very slow (only 1 Hz). Could that be the problem?

I have linked a video of what I see below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jHj5FqOF1nYCibUaxG_4Qu_OmAZMekKa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ah, let me see. You scope is a digital storage one: 
Hitachi VC-6052 Digital Storage Oscilloscope User Manual
https://eclass.teicrete.gr/modules/document/file.php/TH123/Manuals/hitachi%20vc-6025%20Operation_Manual.pdf. So you can use something like ***Single/Stop mode*** to freeze the trace.

Comment: Also if the frequency if low, then it is often difficult to ado auto sync.  Usually I write a little python program is repeat the waveform, say, with 10ms pause, then it is easy to auto sync. There is other things you might have missed, eg. set the tirgger point at the middle of the wave form, and if you are watch more than one wave form, then trigger at the "master" waveform.  Good luck.  Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01:  How do you write a Python program to repeat a signal generated by an analog circuit?

Comment: @JRE, Ah, it depends on what type of analog circuit that is generating the "wave". If the analog circuit is using I2C, SPI, UART, then it is easy, as python can talk with them. If the analog circuit uses manual buttons etc, then python can using GPIO pins to capture the triggering signal. You the OP can let me know more details of the analog circuit, perhaps I can suggest something. By the way, the OP's "wave" might not be a regular periodic wave, eg a triangular wave, but a a periodic, irregular signal, eg charging a cap, or natural things, eg cosmic or asteroid radiation, / to continue, ...

Comment: Or just billiard balls bouncing, ... Any way, perhaps the OP can let us know more details of the signal, ...

Comment: I skimmed the Op's scope manual and found that the scope can be controlled through serial UART port using XT GW Basic.  This reminds me that my US$300 Rigol scope can also do programming through USB port. In other words not by python, but by the scope's native code/library functions.

Comment: @tlfong01 Thanks for your help, pressing the storage button on the bottom of the scope shows the full trace of the signal

Comment: @Vayun, Ah, how nice to hear the good news from you. Have a great new year.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As tlfong01 correctly noted in the comments,the scope you are using is a digital storage oscilloscope.

You need to turn on the storage function of your scope.

From page 22 of the [manual:](https://eclass.teicrete.gr/modules/document/file.php/TH123/Manuals/hitachi%20vc-6025%20Operation_Manual.pdf)

[image]

Push the "Storage" button so that it lights up, and you should be able to see the whole trace.

You may need to turn on the available single shot function.  That is described on page 43 of the manual.

Page 42 describes a "ROLL" mode which may also be useful for your signal.  I am not sure from the description how "ROLL" is activated.  It might be automatically turned on at low sweep speeds in storage mode.